# Safari iOS 9.0.2 jquery bug with .css left/right

Tags: jquery, ios, css, mobile, safari

I have a header navigation menu with multiple menus, and on mobile the menu slides to the left/right when you navigate up or down the submenus. This worked fine until the iOS upgrade to 9.0.2. However, now on this line:

```
menu.css({left: -(100 * positionVariable)) + '%'});
```

the page gets all weird: the body shrinks to half the page size, and the child menu slides in from the right side, starting at the far right of the page and sliding over. When I go to another sub menu, the page halves again. Here's what it looks like at the start of the slide:

[image]

The child menu slides into position, but the body stays shrunk.

I've noticed similar behavior in some of my apps as well (MyFoodDiary for example), where the body shrinks when the page slides to the left, though in this app the body restores its size once the slide is complete. Has anyone else encountered this bug? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Apple states in "What's new in Safari?" [documentation for Safari 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html):

> Viewport meta tags using `width=device-width` cause the page to scale down to fit content that overflows the viewport bounds. You can override this behavior by adding `shrink-to-fit=no` to your meta tag as shown below. The added value will prevent the page from scaling to fit the viewport.

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no“
```